# Powershell add 1 to excel column reference

Tags: excel, powershell, excel.application

Just asked a powershell question here [Finding excel cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866921/powershell-find-excel-cell-reference) and I need to add to it.

The overall code I ended up with is as follows.

```
$filePath = "c:\temp\test.xlsx"

if (test-path $filePath) {
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filePath)
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item("sheet1")
if ([bool]$ws.cells.find("German           Baseload")) {write-host $ws.cells.find("German           Baseload").address(0, 0, 1, 0)}
}
```

This returns a cell reference of F25 which is where the string is located, based on this I want to test the cell next to it in cell reference G25, my question is how do I add one column to F25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing any cell from a known cell reference is simply a matter of applying [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to the original cell reference.

```
$filePath = "T:\TMP\findit.xlsx"
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
if (test-path $filePath) {
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filePath)
$ws = $xl.WorkSheets.item("sheet1")
if ([bool]$ws.cells.find("German")) 
    {
    $found = 1
    $rc1 = $ws.cells.find("German")
    $rc2 = $rc1.offset(0, 1)
    write-host $found
    write-host $rc1.address(0, 0, 1, 1)
    write-host $rc2.address(0, 0, 1, 1)
    write-host $ws.cells.find("German").offset(0, 1).address(0, 0, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

I've reported the offset cell address back redundantly as a way of confirmation.